# Как реализуется логика и структура кода в Unity

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-editor

Все дело в том, что я пишу все свои скрипты как вздумается. Нужно реализовать какую-то вещь, допустим выстрел оружия - лезу в скрипт игрока. Нужно реализовать прыжок - лезу в скрипт игрока и т.д. в итоге в Update скапливается куча условий и код становится невозможным для чтения. Я уверен, что есть грамотная структура построения кода. Слышал, что есть, допустим GameManager, который создает еще менеджеры, например LevelManager, который отвечает за переход между сценами, создание игрока, Sound Manager и т.д. Так в каждом скрипте игрового объекта не скапливается куча условий в Update, а все равномерно распределяется по веткам кода. Я хочу больше знать об этой структуре и как правильно и грамотно её использовать.

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос, попробуйте конкретизировать.

Comment: @Suvitruf сделано

Answer (score 1):

Есть [пара](https://forum.unity.com/threads/help-how-do-you-set-up-a-gamemanager.131170/) офф [уроков](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/projects/tanks-tutorial/game-managers).

Я лишь могу сказать, как делаем мы. У нас есть `GameManager`, у которого в `Update` мы вызываем наш собственный метод в остальных скриптах, передавая туда дельту.

Идея со своим `GameManager`, на самом деле, не только ради удобства. Вызывать самому кастомный метод для апдейта в скриптах по производительности лучше, чем в каждом `MonoBehaviour` переопределять `Update` (когда движок кучу лишней логики делает).